# logout sessionstart and sessiondestroy error

Tags: php

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("config.php");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {          
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
    $id = uniqid() . sha1($myusername);  
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM login WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];  
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;     
    header("location: dpsbn.php");
    }else {
    $error = "Your Login ID or Password is Invalid";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
   include('config.php');

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from login where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");
   }
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(session_destroy()) {
      header("Location: index.html");
   }
?>
```

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /customers/3/e/d/nxges.com/httpd.www/Knight/logout.php:2) in
>   /customers/3/e/d/nxges.com/httpd.www/Knight/logout.php on line 3
>   Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in
>   /customers/3/e/d/nxges.com/httpd.www/Knight/logout.php on line 5

how can i fix it? .. please help me out.

Comment: Have you ever searched for [`headers already sent`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+send) in the search function here?

Comment: For logout use simple code `session_start(); session_destroy(); header('Location: index.html'); exit();`

Comment: that worked for me..thanks a lot. there was a whitespace before <?php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the `sessions_start()`, `headers already sent` and `session_destroy()` warnings, search for empty lines or spaces before the `<?php` tag at the start of your file `logout.php`.

When characters are placed before the `<?php` tag (even *invisible* characters), they are sent to the client.
Then it is too late to send the headers for the session afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the if statement and directly just use header to redirect.

```
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header('Location: index.html');
```